# How can I create a Matrix for different Cash Flows with a for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have 3 Investments with the following Key Points:

```
Investment <- c(900,1200,1800)
Interest <- c(10,20,30) # Yearly 
Payment <- c(1000,1700,2200) #Once
```

The Dates for the Interest / Payment:

```
Inv1 <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to= as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "year")
Inv2 <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2009-02-01"), to= as.Date("2016-02-01"), by = "year")
Inv3 <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-11-15"), to= as.Date("2013-11-15"), by = "year")
```

Now I'd like to construct a Matrix which shows the Interest and the Payment for all Investments.
I tried this: 
1. Dates: 
For each Investment:

```
l <- list(Inv1,Inv2,Inv3) 
d <- data.frame(sapply(l,"[",seq(max(sapply(l,length)))))
d[is.na(d)] <- 0
d
```

For all Investment and for last Payment:

```
Date1 <- c(as.Date("2005-01-01"),Inv1,Inv2,Inv3) #2005-01-01: Day, where the Investments were bought
Last_Payment <- c(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2016-02-01"),as.Date("2013-11-15"))
```

Change to numeric:

```
Date <- as.numeric(Date1)
Last_Payment <- as.numeric(Last_Payment)
```

2.Matrix:

```
CF <- matrix(0L, nrow = 3, ncol = length(Date))
colnames(CF) <- as.character(Date1)
rownames(CF) <- c("I1","I2","I3")
```

3. Loop:

```
for(j in 1:3){
  for(n in 1:length(d)){
    for(m in 1:length(Date)){
      if(Date[m] == d[,n]){
        CF[j,m] <- Interest[j]
      }else if (Date[m] == Last_Payment[j]){
        CF[j,m] <- CF[j,m] + Payment[j]
      }else{
        CF[j,m] <- 0
      }
    }
  }
  CF[j,1] <- - Investment[j]
}

CF
```

As you can see the matrix depicts the payments completely wrong. Can someone help me to correct the loop or is my whole construction wrong? Thanks for any help! 
The Matrix should look like this:

```
   2005-01-01 2009-02-01 2010-01-01 2010-02-01 2010-11-15 2011-01-01 2011-02-01 2011-11-15 2012-01-01 2012-02-01 2012-11-15
I1       -900          0         10          0          0         10          0          0          10          0          0
I2      -1200         20          0         20          0          0          20          0          0         20          0
I3      -1800          0          0          0         30          0          0          30          0          0         30
   2013-01-01 2013-02-01 2013-11-15 2014-01-01 2014-02-01 2015-01-01 2015-02-01 2016-01-01 2016-02-01
I1         10          0          0         10          0          10          0         910          0
I2          0         20          0          0         20          0          20          0       1220
I3          0          0       1830          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

Comment: I did a mistake at Date1: Here's the right Code: Date1 <- c(as.Date("2005-01-01"),Inv1,Inv2,Inv3)

Comment: Can you show a correct desired output using your input? If you cannot render it, type it out or use spreadsheet software. A bit difficult to understand your code.

Comment: Sure, I edited the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are handling disparate types (dates, numeric, etc.), consider sticking with data frame operations and as needed convert final to a matrix. With this approach you even avoid long nested looping.

Specifically, build a long formatted data frame using `Map` (single elementwise loop) through all input parameters and calculate payments with interests using logical `ifelse` calculations. Then, outside loop `rbind` each subset data frame to larger one and `reshape` to wide format for final result.

**Inputs**

```
Investment <- c(900, 1200, 1800)
Interest <- c(10, 20, 30)
Payment <- c(1000, 1700, 2200)

Inv1 <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to= as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "year")
Inv2 <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2009-02-01"), to= as.Date("2016-02-01"), by = "year")
Inv3 <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-11-15"), to= as.Date("2013-11-15"), by = "year")

l <- list(Inv1,Inv2,Inv3) 
Last_Payment <- c(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2016-02-01"),as.Date("2013-11-15"))
```

**Data Frame Build**

```
proc_df <- function(nm, yd, int, l, p, inv) {
  within(data.frame(Investment=nm, Date=c(as.Date("2005-01-01"), yd), Interest=int), {
        Payment  <- ifelse(Date == l, p, 0)
        Payment  <- ifelse(Date == "2005-01-01", -1 * inv, Payment)
        Interest <- ifelse(Date == "2005-01-01", 0, Interest)
        Payment  <- ifelse(Date > "2005-01-01" & Date < l, Interest, Interest + Payment)
  })
}

# BUILD DATA FRAME WITH MAP CALL
invest_df <- do.call(rbind, Map(proc_df, c("Inv1", "Inv2", "Inv3"), 
                                l, Interest, Last_Payment, Payment, Investment,
                                USE.NAMES = FALSE))

# RESHAPE LONG TO WIDE
long_df <- with(invest_df, invest_df[order(Date),])
wide_df <- reshape(invest_df, v.names="Payment", idvar = "Investment",
                   timevar = "Date", drop = "Interest",
                   direction = "wide")

wide_df <- wide_df[c("Investment", unique(paste0("Payment.", long_df$Date)))]
wide_df[is.na(wide_df)] <- 0

# CONVERT TO MATRIX
CF <- as.matrix(wide_df[-1])
rownames(CF) <- wide_df$Investment
colnames(CF) <- gsub("Payment.", "", colnames(CF))
```

**Output** *(unable to render exact output as OP posted)*

```
CF
#      2005-01-01 2009-02-01 2010-01-01 2010-02-01 2010-11-15 2011-01-01 2011-02-01 2011-11-15 2012-01-01 2012-02-01
# Inv1       -900          0         10          0          0         10          0          0         10          0
# Inv2      -1200         20          0         20          0          0         20          0          0         20
# Inv3      -1800          0          0          0         30          0          0         30          0          0
#      2012-11-15 2013-01-01 2013-02-01 2013-11-15 2014-01-01 2014-02-01 2015-01-01 2015-02-01 2016-01-01 2016-02-01
# Inv1          0         10          0          0         10          0         10          0       1010          0
# Inv2          0          0         20          0          0         20          0         20          0       1720
# Inv3         30          0          0       2230          0          0          0          0          0          0
```